# Insert records in two tables plus M:M table - Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have models for three tables in a web API project using Entity Framework: Person, Organization, and PersonOrganization.

```
**Person**
PersonId
Name

**Organization**
OrganizationId
OrgName

**PersonOrganization**
PersonId
OrganizationId
```

A person can belong to more than one org, and an org can have more than one person.  So the question is, in my API controller, what does the code generally look like when I register a new user?  In the same "transaction" I need to create a person, create an org, and a record to create a relationship between the two.  Do I need to do two adds and get the Ids and then do it manually in the code?  There's not a lot of great documentation out there on M:M in EF.

Thank you!

Comment: See codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739164/Entity-Framework-Tutorial-for-Beginners

Comment: Ouch, my pride.  I'm past the basics and I really don't see anything in that article that involves M:M.

Comment: Did you browse the code.   Full Source code can be downloaded.